# eqv? function (DrRacket)

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

There is so much intricacy in the equality functions in DrRacket. There are subtle differences between them I can't understand.

Can you explain why these two results differ? Why for instance 'a' == 'a', but "abc" != "abc"?

```
(eqv? (integer->char 955) (integer->char 955))
; => true

(eqv? (number->string 955) (number->string 955))
; => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the two "(number->string 955)" look the same, they return two separate objects in memory.  With that in mind, let's compare:

```
(eq? (number->string 955) (number->string 955))
#f
```

This is false because eq? cares about identicality, that is: are the things being compared exactly the same object in memory.  This check is fast, but is often not what you are wanting.

```
(eqv? (number->string 955) (number->string 955))
#f
```

This is again false, for the same reason as eq? -- these are not the same objects in memory.  eqv? however makes an exception for numbers and characters: it will compare those by value, so two numbers are eqv? if they have the same value.  This is still fast, and is usually what you want when you're doing number equality tests.

```
(equal? (number->string 955) (number->string 955))
#t
```

Now this is true.  Why?  The objects are still different, but equal? makes exceptions for strings (and other data types too, but I'll keep it simple).  When equal? is given strings, it compares the strings lexically: so if they're the same length and the same sequence of characters, they're "equal".  This is the check you want for strings.

Answer (score 1):

`eqv?` basically does an identity comparison, except that in the case of numbers and characters, then the value is compared instead. This is why two characters with value 955 compare the same.

What do I mean by identity? Consider this:

```
(define a (number->string 955))
(define b (number->string 955))
(string-set! a 0 #\0)
(printf "a = ~s, b = ~s, (eqv? a b) = ~a~%" a b (eqv? a b))
```

You'll notice that only `a`'s string is altered, not `b`'s string. That's because they are different string objects.

The opposite scenario is when aliasing is involved:

```
(define a (number->string 955))
(define b a)
(string-set! a 0 #\0)
(printf "a = ~s, b = ~s, (eqv? a b) = ~a~%" a b (eqv? a b))
```

Here, `a` and `b` point to the same string object, and the effect of the `string-set!` is visible in both places.

Comment: By *identity comparison* you mean that a reference to an object is compared with another reference?

Comment: Yep. So it only compares true if they are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

There are a full two pages in the RNRS specification related to eq?, eqv?, equal? and =. Here is the [Draft R7RS Specification](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/r7rs-draft-8.pdf).  Check it out (pages 30 and 39)!

For eqv?, #t is returned if:

- obj1 and obj2 are both characters and are the same character
  according to the char=? procedure (section 6.6).
- obj1 and obj2 are pairs, vectors, bytevectors, records, or strings
  that denote the same location in the store (section 3.4).

In your case `number->string` returns a new 'location in the store' and thus #f is returned.  (The Scheme standards do not require `number->string` to return a new location; returning the same string would be an optimization.)  Whereas `integer->char` returns the same `char`.